# How can I define a keyboard shortcut for inserting a multilevel list in Word?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I know the keyboard shortcut to start a flat list (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>), but apparently there is none for multilevel lists (at least I found nothing after hours of Googling)..

I tried to define one myself, but couldn't find where.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that you want a multilevel list, what exactly are you looking for? For me, I start a list as you mentioned, with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>. I then begin to type, and what is typed becomes the top-level bullet point.

I can then hit <kbd>return</kbd>, and I am then typing on another top-level bullet point.

I can then hit <kbd>return</kbd> again, followed immediately by <kbd>tab</kbd>, which indents that bullet, thus creating a second level of bullets. To go back, hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

---

Updated due to better understanding of the question:

The easiest way to achieve that, I think, is to create a shortcut for the style directly. To do that (in Word 2013), click the down arrow next to the Multilevel List button on the Home tab of the Ribbon, and then click "Define New List Style..."
[image: Define new list style]

Once you've set the style the way you want it, click the Format button at the bottom-left, and add a keyboard shortcut.

[image: Add keyboard shortcut]

Comment: By "multilevel list" I mean a list that shows list items at different levels with different bullet symbols rather than all at one level or merely indented via tab yet with the same bullet items as you achieve with tab. It's a seperate dedicated list type in Word, see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-new-bullets-numbers-and-multilevel-lists-6c06ef65-27ad-4893-80c9-0b944cb81f5f#multilevel

Comment: Got it, @officeNovice - I've updated my answer to match that question. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks that worked! As a follow-up, how can I change the shortcut for already defined lists? Didn't find an edit option or anything like that for existing lists (nothing on right-click either).

Comment: So it's kind of an interesting question - what you can do is open a blank document, start a multilevel list from a preset, then go through the steps. You'll see in the display that you're working with your currently-selected multilevel list settings, but you'll need to give a new name to that list. In other words, once you select a list and go through the steps, you're basically making a copy of that list preset, and you can give that copy a shortcut. That's the only way I've been able to find, but it does work!

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to edit list styles after you create them. Home > Styles > Expand the styles > Hover over the A icon with a checkmark and it should say Modify Styles > Sort order: Alphabetical > Find your style by name > Select it and click Modify. Then you can assign a shortcut as shown above.